# ffmpeg: nvenc mit crf option - very low bitrate

Tags: linux, nvidia, ffmpeg, gpu, video-encoding

I bought a new computer some time ago.

I installed `nvenc` for `ffmpeg` to encode my videos with the H.264 codec.
To optimize I used the

```
-crf option
```

but something went wrong.

I want to encode a full HD video with originally 6000kbits but `ffmpeg` encode the video with CRF to max 1800kbits. Thats really less and you can see this in the video after the encoding.

I also used

```
-crf 0
```

already but it didn't help.

What can I do to force the bitrate to at least 3000kbit but with the `-crf` option? I don't want to use a fixed bitrate!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -y -i inputfile -c:v nvenc_h264 -b:v 1000k -minrate 500k -maxrate 5000k \
       -tier high -profile:v high -level 4.0 -preset llhq outputfile
```

You will be limited with what options you can use. Faster encodes yes. Quality and control? Not so much. The above example might help you a bit. The `-b:v 1000k -minrate 500k -maxrate 5000k` being the most important part.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-rc constqp -cq 18` for constant quality.

Answer (score -1):

`nvenc` doesn't accept `-crf`. It has its own parameters.

Taken from `ffmpeg` help (`ffmpeg -h encoder=nvenc`):

> `-preset`
>
> Set the encoding preset
>   (one of `slow` = hq 2pass, `medium` = hq, `fast` = hp, hq, hp, bd, ll, llhq, llhp...)

which means something like:

```
-c:v nvenc -preset hp
```